# Пароль к sql то подходит, то не подходит

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, active-directory

Есть некоторое приложение, работает не первый день, всё хорошо. Но иногда (раз в неделю-две) иногда появляется ошибка:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException:
The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
Cannot open database "MyDbName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'mydomain\serviceAccount'.
```

Вопрос больше абстрактный, теоретический: как такое может быть?? Задача запускается раз в три минуты, никто пароль не меняет, через три минуты снова всё работает, периодичность раз в неделю не такая уж и страшная, чтобы не просто забыли-и-забили, сервер никто в этот момент не перезагружал.

Но вот хочется понять, ну как такое вообще возможно?
Можно ли это как-то диагностировать, отловить, понять что произошло?

Поверить в то, что в пароль передаётся по UDP без контрольной суммы целостности пакета? Или дело в том, что как-то sql кеширует хеши паролей, чтобы не дёргать постоянно контроллер домена и пропадает связь с контроллером в момент протухания кеша? Вот как??

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы для базы MyDbName не был включен `AUTO_CLOSE`.

Comment: `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTY('MyDbName','IsAutoClose')` или в опциях БД в интерфейсе SSMS

Comment: напишите лог файл когда `login failed` пусть запишет данные которые пришли в виде пароля и логина так вы хоть поймете что приходит не так

Comment: Это тяжело нагруженный продакшн, на нём разумеется нет автозакрытия базы. Проверил ещё раз -- всё на месте.

Comment: Если проблема в AD, то при использовании SQL-аутентификации она, по идее, должна исчезнуть. Если по-уму сделано, переключение на SQL-логин не должно вызвать сложностей. Какая, кстати, версия (`SELECT @@VERSION`)?

Comment: При возникновении этой ошибки в журнал SQL Server должно падать два события. Одно из них вида `Ошибка: 18456, серьезность: x, состояние: y.` Можно сравнить значение состояния с таблицей https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-error-information и это даст направление для диагностики. Да, пропадание связи с контроллером домена и устаревшие закешированные  пароли могут быть примерами возможных причин.